# Redirect the connection over domain:port to subdomain in nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, routes

i host an application in a docker environment. this application listens on my ip address or domain under port 3030. the connection works fine. but without SSL.

i created a subdomain in nginx to give the application a SSL certificate. this subdomain points to my ip address and the port. the connection via the subdomain application.domain.com works fine via SSL.

but now i want to prevent that the application is accessed via ip/domain:3030.
respectively best to redirect this kind of request to the subdomain to ensure SSL.

what possible options are there for me to prevent access via domain:port to always ensure SSL?

i tried to block this port in ufw. but application is anyway accessible.
i configured my application only to listen on localhost, but its accessible over domain:port without SSL.becuse some docker configurations?

thanks for your advises.

Answer (score 0):

If Nginx and your application are running in Docker then you can put both containers in the same Docker network and only publish only HTTPS port of Nginx container. Nginx will be able to connect to the application via port 3030 even if it is not published when both containers are on the same network. [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#:%7E:text=Each%20container%20can%20now%20look%20up%20the%20hostname%20web%20or%20db%20and%20get%20back%20the%20appropriate%20container%E2%80%99s%20IP%20address.%20For%20example%2C%20web%E2%80%99s%20application%20code%20could%20connect%20to%20the%20URL%20postgres%3A//db%3A5432%20and%20start%20using%20the%20Postgres%20database.)

Example docker compose:

```
services:
  app:
    build: .
    networks:
      - internal_network

  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "443:443"
    networks:
      - internal_network

networks:
  internal_network:
```

If Nginx is not running in Docker, then you can try to use Docker host firewall to whitelist traffic only from Nginx IP address to container
https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/

I think the first option is better